Why does traversing the NeighborLoader affect model accuracy?
The python environment is:
python 3.9.x
PyTorch 2.0.1+cu118
PyG 2.5.3

import os
import copy

import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

from torch_geometric import seed_everything
from torch_geometric.nn import SAGEConv
from torch_geometric.loader import NeighborLoader
from torch_geometric.transforms import RandomNodeSplit
from torch_geometric.datasets import Amazon

seed_everything(0)
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class SAGE(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, hidden_channels, out_channels, p_dropout=0.5):
        super().__init__()
        self.convs = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        self.convs.append(SAGEConv(in_channels, hidden_channels))
        self.convs.append(SAGEConv(hidden_channels, out_channels))
        
        self._p_dropout = p_dropout

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        for i, conv in enumerate(self.convs):
            x = conv(x, edge_index)
            if i < len(self.convs) - 1:
                x = x.relu_()
                x = F.dropout(x, p=self._p_dropout, training=self.training)
        return x

    @torch.no_grad()
    def inference(self, x_all, subgraph_loader):
        for i, conv in enumerate(self.convs):
            xs = []
            for batch in subgraph_loader:
                x = x_all[batch.n_id]
                x = conv(x, batch.edge_index)
                if i < len(self.convs) - 1:
                    x = x.relu_()
                xs.append(x[:batch.batch_size])
            x_all = torch.cat(xs, dim=0).to(device)
        return x_all

dataset_name = 'Computers'

usr_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
data_dir = os.path.join(usr_dir, "data/Amazon")
dataset = Amazon(data_dir, dataset_name,
                    pre_transform=RandomNodeSplit(split='train_rest', num_val=1000, num_test=10000))
data = dataset[0].to(device)

kwargs = {'batch_size': 512, 'num_workers': 6, 'persistent_workers': True}
train_loader = NeighborLoader(data, input_nodes=data.train_mask,
                                num_neighbors=[25, 10], shuffle=True, **kwargs)
val_loader = NeighborLoader(copy.copy(data), input_nodes=data.val_mask,
                            num_neighbors=[-1], shuffle=False, **kwargs)
subgraph_loader = NeighborLoader(copy.copy(data), input_nodes=None,
                                    num_neighbors=[-1], shuffle=False, **kwargs)

del subgraph_loader.data.x, subgraph_loader.data.y
subgraph_loader.data.num_nodes = data.num_nodes
subgraph_loader.data.n_id = torch.arange(data.num_nodes)

hidden_channels = 64
learning_rate = 0.01

model = SAGE(dataset.num_features, hidden_channels,
                dataset.num_classes).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

n_epochs = 25
max_val_acc = 0.
patience = 5
bad_counter = 0
best_model = None

for _ in range(n_epochs):
    model.train()

    total_loss = total_correct = total_examples = 0
    for batch in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y = batch.y[:batch.batch_size]
        y_hat = model(batch.x, batch.edge_index)[:batch.batch_size]
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += float(loss) * batch.batch_size
        total_correct += int((y_hat.argmax(dim=-1) == y).sum())
        total_examples += batch.batch_size

    model.eval()
    val_acc = val_correct = val_examples = 0.
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in val_loader:
            y = batch.y[:batch.batch_size]
            y_hat = model(batch.x, batch.edge_index)[:batch.batch_size]

            val_correct += int((y_hat.argmax(dim=-1) == y).sum())
            val_examples += batch.batch_size

        '''
            Here is a problem.
        '''
        # for i in range(2):
        #     for batch in subgraph_loader:
        #         pass

    val_acc = val_correct / val_examples

    if val_acc >= max_val_acc:
        max_val_acc = val_acc
        best_model = copy.deepcopy(model)
        bad_counter = 0
    else:
        bad_counter += 1

    if bad_counter >= patience:
        break

if best_model is None:
    best_model = copy.deepcopy(model)

best_model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred = best_model.inference(data.x, subgraph_loader).argmax(dim=-1)
test_acc = int((y_pred[data.test_mask] == data.y[data.test_mask]).sum()) / int(data.test_mask.sum())
print(test_acc)

Above is the complete code. When I run the code as is, the model achieves an accuracy of 77.27%. However, if I add this specific section, the model's accuracy increases to 83.63%. What could be the reason for the discrepancy in accuracy before and after removing this section of the code?
for i in range(2):
    for batch in subgraph_loader:
        pass

I am seeking to understand the reason behind this behavior. I look forward to your insights. Thank you!

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
